# How can I unlink a part of a mesh?

Tags: rendering

I duplicated a part of the mesh, since I want to use it for some other purpose, but it is still linked with the previous mesh. Is there a way to unlink them?

[image]

Comment: There are two ways to duplicate a mesh, Shift+D and Alt+D. one duplication keeps the meshes linked, the other doesn't. I just don't remember which one. I think it's Alt+D, but check it once

Comment: Alt+D duplicates linked and Shift+D duplicates without linking - in _Object Mode_. But apart from that, this comment does not help her to unlink objects... she made duplicates of mesh parts in _Edit Mode_ so this doesn't apply here anyway. Barbod's answer is correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to go to Edit Mode, select the faces you want to separate, and press `P`, choose `Selection`.

What happened is that you duplicated the part of your mesh in edit mode :

[image]

which means that the duplicate that you created is still **part of the previous object** i.e. when you go back to object mode, it is still **one object** :

[image]

If you want it to be in a different object, go back to edit mode, select the part you want to separate, press `P` and chose, `Selection` :

[image]

And if you go back to object mode, you will have two separate objects :

[image]

**Side notes** :

In terms of terminology, **one don't say that the meshes are still linked in that case**, we say that the meshes are still *part of the same object*. In Blender, we say that **the meshes are linked when they share the same mesh data-block** this is why you misled @HrishavSaha in the comments.

Comment: thank you @BarbodM that helped